# How can I store an Object as a value in Redis using Spring-Data-Redis?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

I want to store an Object in Redis using Spring-Data-Redis, but it just doesn't save.  If I change payload to a String, it DOES save.  I originally had this as a JsonNode, but this caused a problem with Jackson, so I am using Object to fix that.  The payload is received as Json from a third party.  This is my Entity to be saved:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("FruitPayload")
public class FruitPayload implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private Object payload;
}
```

This is the code that calls it:

```
final Object responseBody = responseEntity.getBody();
FruitPayload fruitPayload = new FruitPayload(key, responseBody);

if(Objects.nonNull(responseBody)) {
      FruitPayload savedPayload = fruitPayloadRepository.save(fruitPayload);                   
 }
```

If I run in debug in Intellij, the savedPayload has the data.  However, if I check Redis, the key is there, but the payload is null.  How can I store this payload in Redis?

Comment: Start by eliminating `implements Serializable` to ensure that your Redis client isn't trying to use Java serialization. (Also, unless you're in a pipeline where you need a method reference `Objects::nonNull`, just use `if (responseBody != null)`.)

Comment: Thanks!  I made those changes, but payload is still null